# ADO Transaction and READPAST

Tags: t-sql, transactions, ado, query-hints

I don't know if this is the best way, if there is a better way, please post.

I have an application that read a file and insert records.
The entire file is processed in one transaction.

Before a record is inserted the table needs to be checked for duplicates
(note: I can't make this a table constraint since there are exceptions)

So the duplicate check is a normal select statement, but the problem is, it reads the uncomitted records from the current transaction.
I have included READPAST and READCOMMITTED hints in the select statement, but that still return the record.

Any ideas?

Comment: how are you going to handle duplicates? do rollback of whole transaction or some other businnes logic? may be it's better to create a unique index for the field and then catch exceptions within application?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue is, duplicates within the same file is acceptable, but not if the record was already created by a previous file.

Comment: Part of the issue is to prevent users importing the file twice. I don't really want to move this to the application but it seems I have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way to implement this within the db is locking table. look at the [ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that could work but concurrency will be a big problem. Ill handle this in the application.